# Instalar Modulo Python Wapplayzer windows

Tags: python, scraping

necesito instalar un módulo en python 3 que seguramente ya esté obsoleto, el módulo es Wappalyzer, antes se suponia que lo podía instalar con --> `pip install python-Wappalyzer`

Pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nose que hacer la verdad, echarme una ayudita porfa

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer `pip` está intentando instalar el modulo desde la caché, según lo que veo. Por lo tanto puede que ese archivo esté corrupto y por ende arroje el error, prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

Dirigete a C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Local\pip
Una vez allí elimina la carpeta cache y de nuevo ejecuta el comando `pip install python-Wappalyzer`

Comment: Nada, sigue petando

Comment: He mirado mejor tu imagen, y lo otro que está ocurriendo es que el error que arroja viene desde el código fuente. Pensé que era la caché porque es lo que dice al principio, pero leyendo un par de lineas más el error viene desde el código fuente, alguna linea de código que está mal escrita y arroja un error. Pero esta app existe ahora para navegadores y tiene la misma función por si te interesa esta es la web oficial https://www.wappalyzer.com/ clickea en descargar y escoge la opción para navegadores.